# How to call a method in digital experience site from Aura Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I am having one aura component in digital site and want to pass a value as a parameter by calling a function in head markup of digital site. But how to pass the value from the aura component to the head markup by calling parameterised function?

Comment: Sharing some code here would be helpful. But if I understand correctly, you want to include some Javascript inside the `<head>` of the Community site and then call that code from your Aura component? [I would recommend using a static resource and loading that resource in your component.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Create dispatcher on AURA like this

```js
document.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent("BeginCheckout", {
    detail: {
      event: "begin_checkout",
      ItemDetails: result,
    },
  })
);
```

Header markup

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('BeginCheckout', function(e) {
        let x  =  e.detail.event
    })
</script>
```